# Assert sorted array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting, chai, assertions, karma-mocha

I'm doing unit testing using javascript testing framework (mocha, chai, etc). How can I assert my array of objects using its name?

I can successfully sort this using localeCompare but I'm not getting what I wanted on my test. It just returns `1` or `-1`.

Here's my a sample of what I want to sort.

```
var Stuffs = [
     { name: "PWE", address: "1234567890" },
     { name: "NSA", address: "1234567890" },
     { name: "AVE", address: "1234567890" },
     { name: "QRE", address: "1234567890" },
  ]
```

How can I assert this to `["AVE", "NSA", "PWE", "QRE"]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `reduce()` method of array and then `sort()`.

**DEMO**

```js
var Stuffs = [{ name: "PWE", address: "1234567890" },
     { name: "NSA", address: "1234567890" },
     { name: "AVE", address: "1234567890" },
     { name: "QRE", address: "1234567890" }];
     
let sortedArr = Stuffs.reduce((r,{name})=>r.concat(name),[]).sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(sortedArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired Array, you can use:

```
Stuffs.map(({ name }) => name).sort();
```

Comment: This worked too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using chai

```
assert.deepInclude(Stuffs, {name: "AVE"});
assert.deepInclude(Stuffs, {name: "NSA"});
assert.deepInclude(Stuffs, {name: "QRE"});
assert.deepInclude(Stuffs, {name: "PWE"});
```

Edit: I may have misunderstood it to mean, how can assert that the array has those values.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need a sorted array to compare it to. The original array needs to be cloned (shallow is fine for this) since [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) will modify the array it is called on. Using [`from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to generate the clone, we can then alphabetically sort the new array to get the desired order.

```js
const sortedStuffs = Array.from(stuffs).sort(({name: a}, {name: b}) => a.localeCompare(b));
```

Finally using [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), we can compare the names for each element to see if they match. As soon as one fails, the returned value will be `false`

```js
stuffs.every(({name}, i) => name === sortedStuffs[i].name);
```

Full working example:

```js
const stuffs = [
 {name: "PWE", address: "1234567890"},
 {name: "NSA", address: "1234567890"},
 {name: "AVE", address: "1234567890"},
 {name: "QRE", address: "1234567890"}
];

const sortedStuffs = Array.from(stuffs).sort(({name: a}, {name: b}) => a.localeCompare(b));

const isSorted = stuffs.every(({name}, i) => name === sortedStuffs[i].name);

console.log(isSorted);
```

Comment: Thanks. But this returns true.

Comment: @evee It returns `false` for me. What browser did you run the code on?

Comment: Ah, right. Its returns false, sorry.

Comment: @eevee I am a bit confused. Were you asking how to assert if the array is ordered by the `name` of the elements or just how to get a new array of just the sorted names?

Comment: I'm trying to assert the sorted array. N. Jadhav and Dan's answer helped. :)

Comment: @eevee So, based off of their answers you wanted a new array of sorted name values. What is the assertion then?

Comment: Yes. Using N. Jadhav's code, my assertion is assert.deepEqual(sortedArr, ["AVE", "NSA", "PWE", "QRE"])